# Javascript: Return original innerHTML on mouseout

Tags: javascript, html

I am sorry for this very basic question. I am very new to javascript and learning it.
I am stuck with one easy problem-

This is what i am trying to do-

I have a header that has some `innertext`

```
<h1 id="bd" onmouseover="fun1()" onmouseout="fun2()"> sample</h1>
```

I am chaging innerHTML of this header on mouseover like this-

```
function fun1()
{
document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML="a";
}
```

well on mouseout i do the same but for getting original innerHTML for this header tag.

```
function fun2()
{

document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML=document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML;

}
```

But onmouseout function shows me changed innerHTML, that is `a` in this case.

How do i get original innerHTML `sample` again onmouseout?

I want this to be done in javascript.

**I tried another way more**

```
function fun1()
{
document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML="a";
}
function fun3()
{
var ds=document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML;
alert(ds);

}
function fun2()
{

document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML=fun3();

}
```

but it is not working also.

Answer (score 2):

A very generic version would be the following:

First change your markup a bit:

```
<h1 id="bd" onmouseover="fun1(this)" onmouseout="fun2(this)"> sample</h1>
```

This way you don't need to look up your element again in your callback function. This works then for more than one element you mouse over. Then you go:

```
function fun1(elm) {
    if (!fun1.cache) fun1.cache = {}; // extend your function with a cache
    fun1.cache[elm.id] = elm.innerHTML; // write into cache -> fun1.cache.bd
    elm.innerHTML = 'a';
}

function fun2(elm) {
    if (fun1.cache && fun1.cache[elm.id]) { // see if cache exists and...
        elm.innerHTML = fun1.cache[elm.id]; // read from it
    }
}
```

This way you build a caching system that doesn't need an extra global variable but stays closer to your function.

The next step would be to use only one function and send the new value as a parameter. Create something like a toggle function:

```
<h1 id="bd" onmouseover="fun(this, 'a')" onmouseout="fun(this)"> sample</h1>
```

and then your function:

```
function fun(elm, newValue) {
    if (!fun.cache) fun.cache = {};
    var value = newValue || fun.cache[elm.id]; // no newValue means recover old value
    fun.cache[elm.id] = elm.innerHTML; // alway save the old value
    elm.innerHTML = value;
}
```

If you need more explanations about `this` and creating `Object`s just leave a comment to this answer and I'll come back with more details...
Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Store the first innerHtml in a **global variable** ,and use this variable to backup the first innerHtml.

```
var oldInner = '';
function fun1()
{
oldInner  = document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML="a";
}

function fun2()
{

document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML=oldInner;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store the original value somehow:

```
var originalInnerHTML = "";

function fun1()
{ 
    originalInnerHTML = document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML="a";
}

function fun2()
{
    document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML=originalInnerHTML
}
```

Currently you just get the existing innerHTML and set it as the new innerHTML - it's always going to be the same. So this line never changes anything:

```
document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML=document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

once you have changed the innerhtml of an element, old data is gone

In order to get the old data you first need to have it store in some other place.

For ex : on mouseover you can first copy the original html to a hidden div, and upon mouseout you can again copy from the hidden div to the main div.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A very easy implementation will be to have the two text you want to display in the div. so you have:

```
<h1 id="bd">
    <span id='sample1'>sample1</span>
    <span id='sample2' style='display: none'>a</span>
</h1>


var el = document.getElementById("bd");
el.onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementById("sample1").setAttribute("style", "display: none");
    document.getElementById("sample2").setAttribute("style", "");
}

el.onmouseout = function() {
   document.getElementById("sample2").setAttribute("style", "display: none");
   document.getElementById("sample1").setAttribute("style", "");
}
```